# Harry Potter's detention with Dolores Umbridge

Tags: harry-potter, the-order-of-the-phoenix

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, after Umbridge made him write with the punishment quill, did he tell Professor McGonagall about it, as Hermione suggested?

And if he did, what was Professor McGonagall's action? Did she have a confrontation with Umbridge?

Comment: I have removed the book part 1) to make it on-topic here 2) this happens in movies as well 3) the answer referenced from both movies and books is also acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*He did not go to any teachers about doing "lines with that special quill".*

Actually, Hermione suggested that Harry go to Dumbledore, but Harry said he would not go. (I looked for a clip, but could not find one. All the searches go directly to Harry and Umbridge.) Hermione then says that it is simple (a clear-cut case for which any teacher would act on behalf of the student). But Harry says something to the effect that whatever it is, it is not simple. And then he walks away.

In the book, it's Ron that tells Harry that he should seek assistance from McGonagall. Harry retorts that he is not certain if she had enough pull to defy Umbridge. Then Ron suggests doing to Dumbledore. But Harry is upset with Dumbledore because he has refused to speak with Harry for the longest time.

McGonagall does have a confrontation with Umbridge much later in the story, and for different reasons.

Comment: If I remember rightly (and I probably don't) Harry says, in the films, that he doesn't want to give Umbridge the satisfaction [of telling another teacher] which is why he lets it go.

Comment: @gabe3886 You are correct. He did say that and also that Dumbledore has a lot on his mind. These statements served mainly to brush off the idea of reporting it (because the situation was not simple).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put - no he doesn't. He doesn't want to go to Dumbledore because he was upset with him. He doesn't think McGonagall could overpower Umbridge (which was so wrong!).

I know this is mentioned extremely well in the answer above but just to add - when you are so into the story - try the books! They are magic that you will love.